# Fetching collection fields in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is there any way through which i can fetch all unique key from a collection in mongoose.
One solution that I come across in mongo

```
  var mr = db.runCommand({
    "mapreduce": "users",
    "map": function() {
      for (var key in this) {
        emit(key, null);
      }
    },
    "reduce": function(key, stuff) {
      return null;
    },
    "out": "users" + "_keys"
  })
  db[mr.result].distinct("_id")
```

But since mongoose does not have any runCommand  so the query fails in mongoose .I also try executeDbCommand but its not working for me.

Is there any alternative solution available , or any way through which i can fetch all the key of collection(collection name is pass as a parameter).

Comment: https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/1781

Comment: @ExplosionPills : its mention there , that we can access the drivers db object like :

YourModel.db.db

can you explain me this :) .